# Adding variables in AndroidManifest.xml, MainActivity.java and MainApplication.java in React Native

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to pass variables to `AndroidManifest.xml`, `MainActivity.java` and `MainApplication.java`?

I am planning to change the **bundleId** based on the environment I am running ex.: (**com.app.dev** and **com.app.prod**).

Right now I can easily pass variables to AndroidManifest.xml to change the app label, version code, version name and so on except the package name. Whenever I pass the variable `"${bundleId}"`, it does not read the value inside the variable instead it reads the variable itself which is "${bundleId}" so it gives me an error.

Or is there any way on how to do environment setting on `AndroidManifest.xml`, `MainActivity.java` and `MainApplication.java`?

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out in a much easier way.

1. I created a folder called dev and prod
2. Inside these folders are the xml and java files that contains bundle ID or package ID for each environment.
3. I created a bash script that will copy and paste the AndroidManifest.xml, MainActivity.java and MainApplication.java files from dev or prod folder to /android/app/src/main/... when I run the app.

I worked well :)

Case closed